# Seagull Software JWalk Java Client There is no suitable Java Runtime Environment (JRE)

Tags: java

So i want to access this [site](https://prprod.insurity.com/MassXpressUmsC11/Login/PR30250007.html)

But i got this error while i want to get in

There is no suitable Java Runtime Environment (JRE) found on this system.
The LegaSuite GUI Java Client requires version 1.4.2 or higher to run correctly.

Install the latest Java Runtime Environment

i have java 1.8 on my pc. It works. I have ...java/jre1.8/bin add to my enviroment path.

I try this site throught ie and chrome

I have javascript enabled in browsers

Comment: just a guess, but does your browser allow java applets?

Comment: yes because i haven't installed java in my pc still the site is working perfectly.

Comment: i have javaScript enabled